# Adobe cq5 installation

Tags: adobe, aem

I have an installation file for cq5 **cq-author-4503.jar** file. I double click on the jar file then one window came adobe quickstart but the editor is not installing can anyone pls help me

Comment: Try following quick tips: 1. Change port to 4502, as 4503 is used for publish 2. Check your logs for error and see whats missing

Comment: @MohitBansal though the keyword "author" in the jar should start an author, but you're probably right with the port. At OP: check the documentation for startup options: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html

Answer (score 1):

If using the command line, for a 32bit VM type:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar cq-author-p4502.jar
```

Or, for a 64bit VM, type:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -jar cq-author-p4502.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In adobe cq5 your browser is your editor. Try to open this link http://localhost:4502 to open your editor if you have installed adobe cq5 on 4502 port. For more reference visit this link [https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html][1]